# nth-child(odd) affecting all children instead of odd

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, styled-components

I have a span on my portfolio that I want to reverse with every odd entry. The projects are dynamically rendered from an array that's being mapped over and passed into this component via props.

I'm using styled-components also.

The issue I'm having is that odd or even within the nth-child affects all of the projects. For example, when it's on odd, none of them are reversed but when it's on even all of them are reversed. What have I missed here?

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could post a verifiable example and not screenshots of code?

Comment: Please refer to this article on [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

`<SummaryContainer/>` is not getting mapped. That means, i'm assuming that you are running the map on entire `Project` component. That is why , nth-child is not working. An easier way to do this is,

Step 1: Pass `index` as a prop to `Project Component`.

Step 2: Pass style to add row or row-reverse based on odd even logic

```
<JobContainer style={{ flexDirection: props.index % 2 ? 'row' : 'row-reverse' }}>

</JobContainer>
```

Step 3: `<JobContainer /> component` just use this style as `prop.style`

This should solve your issue.

Comment: This should be easily accomplished in a global CSS style that doesnt require wiring styles into your actual dom elements. Nth-child should work if correctly nested.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But for that we need the entire code. To see the proper nesting. According to current code nth-child won't work for <SummaryContainer />. We can add a proper nesting in <JobContainer /> css for nth-child to work. 

But according to current code I could suggest the above answer.